# Insert Bangla text in Database from C# from using SQL statement

Tags: c#

I write the following code:

```
string.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_detail VALUES('{0}','{1}')",schoolName, schoolId)
```

Now, how would i insert bangla text into the database. (the value of schoolName and schoolId will provide from textbox. User will give input in Bangla)

Comment: What is Bangla? What is the problem that you have? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: you mean Bangladesh languange?? Have you tried to use the NVARCHAR data type?

Comment: Bengali language, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MySQL DB. Make sure your code is supporting `utf-8`, that is `schoolName` should be in correct/bangla format. To addon, you need `utf-8` in db as well. So, while creating table use `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`.

For example create table should be as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE MyScoolData (
  `schoolId` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schoolName` txt,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schoolId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

More info [here](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).